# Why won't the output of the client be printed to the screen?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to inject remote code through sockets, but for some reason, when writing the command `cd` or any other command, which in turn gives me an answer through the client, the answer won't be outputted to the screen.

I've tried various ways of outputting to the screen but none of them work.

Server part which outputs:

```
void *ReadAndWriteSocket(void *entrypoint) {

        char message[256];
        char buffer[256];

        while (1) {

        if((sockStructure.n = recv(sockStructure.newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) > 0) { 


        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer) - 1; i++) {

        printf("%s", buffer[i]);

        }

        }


        }
        scanf("%s", &message);
        send(sockStructure.newsockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);

}
```

Client code:

```
require 'socket'
require 'open3'

def createClient(hostname, port)

  s = TCPSocket.new hostname, port

    while line = s.gets
      if line == "exit"
        s.close
      elsif line[0..1] == "cd"
        output = Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd + "/" + line[2..line.size].delete(" \t\n\r\0"))
        s.puts(Dir.pwd)
      end
      stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(line)
      s.puts("#{stdout.read}")
    end
end

createClient("127.0.0.1", 8082);
```

Comment: You forgot to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and you should learn about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Please read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you receive even the tiniest drop of data, you block in `scanf` rather than trying to receive more data. You either need to support moving data in both directions at the same time (waiting for input in `scanf` and data in `recv`) at the same time or you need to be smarter about when you change the direction.

Consider the following scenario:

1. You call `ReadAndWriteSocket`.
2. Your call to `recv` gets just an "H", the very first byte of the message.
3. You pass that "H" to `printf`, but nothing gets printed because your standard output is line buffered.
4. You call `scanf` and wait forever, but nothing is coming because the user has no intention of typing anything until they see the received message.
5. Your code will never call `recv` again, too bad since the rest of the received message is waiting in the receive buffer but you're stuck in `scanf`.

When you have code that moves data in two directions, you must be absolutely sure that you never block waiting to receive data in one direction when the data you should be waiting for is coming in the other direction. Your code has nothing to prevent this.

**Update:** Problems with your new code:

```
void *ReadAndWriteSocket(void *entrypoint) {

    char message[256];
    char buffer[256];

    while (1) {

    if((sockStructure.n = recv(sockStructure.newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) > 0) {
```

What's going on here? You can only pass a string to `strlen`. But `buffer` doesn't contain a string here (it's uninitialized on the first pass and contains an unrelated length on subsequent passes). So you're passing a nonsensical value for the length to `recv`.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer) - 1; i++) {

    printf("%s", buffer[i]);
```

Two problems here: First, `buffer[i]` is not a string and the `%s` format specifier is for strings. Second, standard output is line buffered, so unless the buffer happens to contain a line, it won't show.

```
    }

    }


    }
    scanf("%s", &message);
```

Why are you waiting for user input here? What if you only received a tiny fraction of the message and didn't even receive an entire line and so haven't ouputted anything yet? How do you know the next thing you need to do is receive input from the user and not receive the rest of the message?

```
    send(sockStructure.newsockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);
}
```

If you have some protocol that specifies who will send when and who will receive when and what constitutes a message and when to wait for user input, you have to write code that implements that protocol. Otherwise, you'll get stuck in `scanf` waiting for input when there's data in the socket's receive buffer.

Comment: What do you mean block in scanf? Doesn't it get the userinput, send it and then go back the beggining of the loop, printing the output?

Comment: Your code calls `recv` exactly once, then it blocks in `scanf`. While it's blocked in `scanf`, it can't receive anything from the socket. So, say in your first call to `recv`, you get just the very first byte of the response. You then block in `scanf` forever since no input is coming. You either need to loop in calls to `recv` without calling `scanf` until you have the entire response or you need to do both at the same time.

Comment: Edited my code to be akin to your advice, although it still does not print anything to the screen. :/

Comment: Your code makes no sense now. The `%s` format specifier is for strings, but `buffer[i]` is not a string. Standard output is still line buffered and your code still does not intelligently decide which direction to wait for. (See updates.)

Comment: I think maybe there's a higher level concept you might be missing. TCP is not a message protocol, it's a byte stream protocol. If you want to pass messages using TCP, you can, but you need a message protocol layered on top of TCP in order to do that. It won't just work by itself. If you're not experienced with TCP, it's very helpful to document your message protocol in detail before you even start writing code. The protocol must specify such things as the precise byte contents of a message and how each side will find the boundaries between the messages.